# Node not throwing Stack Overflow exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

I'm trying to force a stack overflow with this code:

```
// Throws stack overflow exception

var count = 0;

try {
    (function curse() {
        console.log(count++);
        curse();
    })();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR');
    console.log(e.message);
}
```

However, when I run it, it prints numbers to the screen and then exits gracefully.  No exception thrown, I can remove the `try-catch` and still no exception is output to the console.

Why don't I get an exception message dumped to the console?

Node version is `v0.12.2`, V8 is `3.28.73`.

Comment: Do you mean `curse()`?  It's called and the integers are printed out to the screen as I'd expect.  It just finishes and exits though.

Comment: It does when I run it in jsfiddle - provide more information (what is the js being run in?)

Comment: prints what to the screen, and endless stream of numbers? what node.js version?

Comment: @MaineCoder It's in the title: "Node not throwing (...)"

Comment: @MaineCoder I did put it in JSFiddle, I didn't link it as it crashes the browser so I thought it would be a bit mean.  It prints out numbers, get's slow, then throws a `RangeError` and then just goes a bit nuts as expected.

Comment: @KevinB It prints numbers to the screen, then stops and the command prompt is left.  No error message.  Node version is `v0.12.2`, V8 is `3.28.73`.

Comment: It prints some garbage containing the word `null` at the end if you remove the try/catch, if that helps.

Comment: @AaronDufour That's odd, mine doesn't.  I get the same behaviour whether the `try-catch` is there or not.  Just a long list of numbers followed by the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to the latest [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (currently v4.1.2), you will probably be able to see the exception message dumped to the console. This seems to have been a bug in older versions of node.js.

Also, in your current version of node.js, if you took out the `console.log(count++);` statement, you might have been able to see the exception message. At least, that worked for me with v0.10.26.

Comment: I don't know how I had such an old node.  I've updated it, same result though.